# Java update Jtextarea while looping the server response from socket

Tags: java

In the code below, I noticed that when I uncomment the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);` it shows the two messages while if it is commented it only show the `"This might well be displayed before the other message."`. How should I adjust the code below to display the two messages without the JoptionPane?

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), 80);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    pw.print("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    pw.print("Host: " + host + "\r\n\r\n");
    pw.flush();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String t;
    while ((t = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);
        Runnable doHelloWorld = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello World on " + Thread.currentThread());
            myJtextarea.append(t + "\r\n");
        }
};
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doHelloWorld);
 System.out.println("This might well be displayed before the other message.");
        }
    }
    br.close();
    s.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Do you want them displayed in sequence? Then don't launch one in a separate thread.

Comment: Sorry I take comment back. I misread your code

Comment: Yes I want them displayed in sequence at the same time update the JtextArea in real time.

Comment: Does the final text in the text area look as you expect?

Comment: yes but it happens after the socket finishes its job which is almost 5 minutes long. I want to update the JtextArea per line.

Comment: I think your call to the server is running in the swing thread.  Make sure it doesn't.